# How do I create t-sql from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a string variabled declared as so:

```
declare @myGeniuses as nvarchar(8000);
set @myGeniuses = ' in (1,2,3)';
```

I want to apply my variable in a select statement like so:

```
select * from GENIUSES where GeniusId @myGeniuses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use sp_executesql to achieve that result which lets you pass in your query statement as a string and executes it.

See this for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Example usage:

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @filter AS NVARCHAR(500); 
SET @filter = ' in (1,2,3)'; 
SET @sql = 'select * from GENIUSES where GeniusId' + @filter; 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I'd really like to only apply this after the (where GeniusId) part of the code.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work do you have an example.

Comment: It's similar to just using the EXEC statement:               `DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @filter AS NVARCHAR(500);
SET @filter = ' in (1,2,3)';
SET @sql = 'select * from GENIUSES where GeniusId' + @filter;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql`;

Comment: Thank you, Could you please put that in your answer so when I refer back to it I won't have to scrounge around for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t nvarchar(max)
set @t='select * from GENIUSES where GeniusId'+ @myGeniuses

exec @t
```

Comment: @RetroCoder: SQL Server 2000 doesn't have a `nvarchar(max)` type - use `nvarchar(4000)` instead. Also: you should **tell us** about the version of SQL Server you're using - some features are present (or not) in a given version... (and the 2000 version is definitely no longer mainstream)

Answer (score 1):

you would do ...

```
exec ('select * from GENIUSES where GeniusId' + @myGeniuses)
```

Comment: This works great in sql2000. Is there a way to trick it to think the string is actually a t-sql statement?

Comment: I mean by convincing the command that the contents inside the string are part of the current command statement.  Perhaps a cast operation, or is this a security feature.

Comment: Guess you mean like doing something like what you tried so it is a `select` statement.  Well, no that can't be done that I know of (and especially not in SQL server 2000), you need to use an `exec` if you want to run dynamic queries like this